# How to show the x-axis line if i have very long data in charts with height fixed and overflow as auto?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

So, I am new to reactjs and trying to use react-chartjs-2 npm package. But, my data is very big, so added fixed height and overflow as auto. That, made the x-axis not visible till u reach the end. What I want is that i have the scroll functionality but visible x-axis.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {HorizontalBar} from 'react-chartjs-2';
import patvanJspData from './patvanJspData.json'
const horizontal={
  height:'50vh',
  overflow:'auto'
}
console.log('patvanJspData:',patvanJspData)

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={value:'Overall',jspdata:[],label:[]}
   this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this)
 }
 componentDidMount(){
   let label=[...patvanJspData.Patvan_List]
   let jspdata=label.map((value)=>{
     return patvanJspData[value].Total
   })
   this.setState({jspdata:jspdata,label:label})
 }
 handleChange(event) {
   let jspdata
   if(event.target.value!=='Overall'){
   jspdata=this.state.label.map((value)=>{
     if(patvanJspData[value][parseInt(event.target.value)]!==undefined){
       return patvanJspData[value][event.target.value].Total
    }
   })
   }else{
     jspdata=this.state.label.map((value)=>{
    return patvanJspData[value].Total
   })
   }
   this.setState({jspdata:jspdata,value: event.target.value})
 }
 render() {
   const data = {
  labels: this.state.label,
  datasets: [
    {

      label: 'My First dataset',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
      borderWidth: 1,
      hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.4)',
      hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
      data: this.state.jspdata
    }
  ]
};
return (
  <div className="container">
  <h2>Bar Example (custom size)</h2>
  <span>Select Year: </span>
  <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
    <option value="Overall">Overall</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
  </select>
  <div style={horizontal}>
  <HorizontalBar
      data={data}
      width={100}
  />
  </div> 
  </div>
);
}
}

export default App;
```

As i described I would want a visible x-axis throughout the scroll. Thanks.
Reference:

- **Deployed Link**: https://reverent-cray-89cced.netlify.com/
- JSON DATA: Go to the deployed link and see the console.

Comment: Show your ./patvanJspData.json' too, if possible create the stackblitz link

Comment: Dude its a big ass data containing 50 element in a array.

Comment: Add 2-3 elements that should be ok

Comment: see the console of deployed link